Why does a Python class need to rely on a function defined outside of its scope?
I came across the following code that draws a health bar above a sprite
import pygame
import math

def draw_health_bar(surf, pos, size, borderC, backC, healthC, progress):
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, backC, (*pos, *size))
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, borderC, (*pos, *size), 1)
    innerPos  = (pos[0]+1, pos[1]+1)
    innerSize = ((size[0]-2) * progress, size[1]-2)
    rect = (round(innerPos[0]), round(innerPos[1]), round(innerSize[0]), round(innerSize[1]))
    pygame.draw.rect(surf, healthC, rect)
    
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.original_image = pygame.image.load('CarBlue64.png')
        self.original_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, 90)
        self.image = self.original_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(x, y))
        self.direction = pygame.math.Vector2((0, -1))
        self.velocity = 5
        self.position = pygame.math.Vector2(x, y)
        self.health = 10

...

    def draw_health(self, surf):
        health_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.original_image.get_width(), 7)
        health_rect.midbottom = self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top
        max_health = 10
        draw_health_bar(surf, health_rect.topleft, health_rect.size, 
                (0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), self.health/max_health) 

Can someone please help me understand the following questions:

Why was the function draw_health_bar declared outside of the class Player?
Can I move the function draw_health_bar inside the class Player, then define the function draw_health inside the Player's child class? For example:

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

...
    def draw_health_bar(surf, pos, size, borderC, backC, healthC, progress):
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, backC, (*pos, *size))
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, borderC, (*pos, *size), 1)
        innerPos  = (pos[0]+1, pos[1]+1)
        innerSize = ((size[0]-2) * progress, size[1]-2)
        rect = (round(innerPos[0]), round(innerPos[1]), round(innerSize[0]), round(innerSize[1]))
        pygame.draw.rect(surf, healthC, rect)

...

class A(Player):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        super().__init__(x, y)

...

    def draw_health(self, surf):
        health_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, self.original_image.get_width(), 7)
        health_rect.midbottom = self.rect.centerx, self.rect.top
        max_health = 10
        super().draw_health_bar(surf, health_rect.topleft, health_rect.size, 
                (0, 0, 0), (255, 0, 0), (0, 255, 0), self.health/max_health) 


The intention is probably that the function could be used to draw health bars for other game entities.  That wouldn't be possible if it was part of the Player class.


Why was the function draw_health_bar declared outside of the class Player?

Because it doesn't do anything that's Player-specific. It doesn't refer to any instance variables of the Player object, or call any Player methods.

Can I move the function draw_health_bar inside the class Player, then define the function draw_health inside the Player's child class?

You could. But if you do this, you should add the @staticmethod decorator, since it doesn't have a self parameter. And then you should call it using Player.draw_health_bar(...) syntax -- the class hierarchy doesn't establish a scope for names.

Thank you for a great answer. I might have follow-up questions when applying your advice to my specific task.

If you're already in an instance method, there's no particular reason not to call an @staticmethod as self.draw_health_bar(...); the whole point of the @staticmethod decorator is that it allows you to call the method via an instance of the class without implicitly passing self as the first argument (and it's actually very slightly faster than calling it on the class itself last I checked, thanks to how the descriptor protocol works, with the instance checking the type, while the class checks the [trivial] metaclass).

@ShadowRanger, your explanation is above my level. Did you mean that I should define def self.draw_health_bar() inside the child class A(Player) instead of Player.draw_health_bar() as suggested by @Barmar?  Would you mind illustrating with an example in the form of a code?

He just meant you can call it as self.draw_health_bar(...) instead of Player.draw_health_bar(...).

As I'm not allowed to use @staticmethod (outside of my study's scope), how can I modify the example code given in my OP to draw a health bar above a loaded image? That is, I have a class Player and a class Fighter(Player) The class Fighter will load an image of the fighter into the video game. How can make a health bar appear above that fighter's image?

What problem are you trying to solve? If it doesn't need to be a class method, just write it outside the class as in the original code.

I'm required to demonstrate my knowledge of OOP via inheritance. So my interpretation is I have to create a draw health bar function in the parent Player class then polymorphing it in each subclass of Player such as Fighter, Killer etc.

If you don't want a class method, just give it a self argument, but don't use it.
